# NirCmd setsysvolume startup issue

Tags: nircmd

Copying the string "nircmd.exe setsysvolume 49151" (without quotes) into command prompt works, when i copy it into an example.cmd file and doubleclick to open it, it does not work.
What am i doing wrong?

I am trying to execute this at startup to set my volume at 75/100.

Comment: It works well in my testing. Perhaps you need to specify the entire path. For me this is like this `"C:\Program Files\Nirsoft Package\NirSoft\x64\nircmd.exe" setsysvolume 49151`, but use the path as it is on your computer.

Comment: I found the culprit, i used notepad++ to save the .txt file before changing it to .cmd, it used UTF-8 to encode, changed it to ANSI, saved and renamed to .cmd and it works now.